# const correctness for containers

Tags: c++, stl, const-correctness

After years of blindly accepting the fact that `std::vector<T>::operator[] const` returns `const_reference`, but, in light of how const works for smart pointers, I'm now beginning to wonder why it and the rest of the STL containers were designed that way. It seems that the "constness" of a `const std::vector` is being applied both to the vector and its elements, whereas for smart pointers the "constness" only applies to the pointer and not the element to which it's pointing.

To clarify, it seems like there should be a vector-like container where `const` just means that a user can't change the size of the container, but the elements in the container are mutable. My main question is: Is there something that would prevent this type of container from being "const correct"?

It seems that there are a couple of hackish workarounds by adding an extra layer of indirection (e.g. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> const`) to accomplish this, but I'm looking for something a little less awkward in terms of maintenance.

As an aside, if smart pointers were incorporated into the language before the STL containers, would the const accessors still have been defined the way they are today?

Comment: You could define your own class that uses composition to act indirecly on a `mutable std::vector` and ensures const correctness (in your sense) through the public member functions.

Comment: `std::vector<T>::operator[]` returns a reference. `std::vector<T>::operator[] const` returns a const reference.

Comment: @Marshall Clow Somehow that fell out of my original draft. I'll add it back in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> To clarify, it seems like there should be a vector-like container where const just means that a user can't change the size of the container, but the elements in the container are mutable.

That's `std::array`. You set the size at compile time. For setting the size at constructor-time there's the proposed `dynarray`.

Comment: That seems reasonable for vector, but what about the other STL containers? Seems reasonable to have something like std::map where you can't add or remove keys, but the values are mutable.

Comment: The standard is library is not a collection of all possible things.

Comment: As constness does not imply values known at compile time, I'd rather compare the new array spans/views with non-resizable containers of mutable elements. But for a reason unbeknownst to me, those views have the same behaviour as `vector`: Their operations behave as if the view is its elements - `operator==` compares elements, and `const` is deep as opposed to the pointer they wrap.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class mut_wrapper {
    mutable T value;
public:
    template<class... Args>
    mut_wrapper(Args... args) : value(args...) {}
    operator T&() const { return value; }
};

template<class T>
using mut_vector = std::vector<mut_wrapper<T>>;

void try_modify_value(const mut_vector<int> &v) {
    ++v[0];
}

// doesn't compile
// void try_push(const mut_vector<int> &v) {
//     v.push_back(3);
// }

void try_push_mutable(mut_vector<int> &v) {
    v.push_back(3);
}
```

The forwarding constructor and implicit conversion makes `mut_wrapper<T>` behave exactly like a `T&`, and the type alias makes `mut_vector` easy to use.

As required, `const mut_vector<T>` values can have their elements mutated but cannot have elements added or removed.

There's also no additional storage overhead or unnecessary pointer indirection, like there would be with `unique_ptr`.

This approach generalises to other STL containers, but shouldn't be used for keys in ordered or hashed data structures (e.g. keys of `unordered_map`, `set`) for obvious reasons.